# Https outputStream

Tags: android, json, response, httpsurlconnection

I am working on an android app that must post a json object on a server and get a json response. Although when I use HttpURLConnection it works perfect when I switch to HttpsURLConnection my app does not send my json object and server response is always null. Here is my background thread

```
try {
            // uri is my https link
            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(7000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("action", "act");
            object.put("usern", name);
            object.put("msg", msg);
            // up to here it works fine but won't post json
            // neither gets a response from server 
            // and goes directly to onPostExecute
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(object.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            String result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(result);
            in.close();
            serverResponse = myResponse.getString("res");
            messagetoShow = myResponse.getString("msg");
            return myResponse.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Since HttpsURLConnection is a subclass of HttpURLConnection I think it should work the same. Any ideas?

Comment: forgot to mention that using the same https link and json object I want to post in soapUi I get the correct response

Comment: I found out that I get IoException in 
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream(); 
and InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
but how can I fix it?